# Find specific property in MongooseJS array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB object with an array of objects inside it, structured as

```
{
    otherInfo: String,
    invited: [{
        code: String,
        email: String
    }],
    moreInfo: String
}
```

I'm trying to find a specific object in that array with a specific code, and then get the email associated with that code.
I have tried `.find({ invited: { $all: [{ code: 1234567890 }]}})` but it didn't return anything. I have tried other variations on it none none of them seem to have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to solve your query

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

## Try this

```
db.collection.find({ invited: { $elemMatch: { code: 1234567890 } } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => { //change with your endpoint code
 const findCode = await Models.find({}) //change name of your models
 const result = findCode.invited.filter(item => {
   item.code ==  '1234567890'
 })
 console.log(result);
})
```

Or try with this:

```
Models.find().elemMatch("invited", {"code":"1234567890"}).exec((err,result)=>{
    console.log(result);
}) //change your Models name
```

Comment: This makes the database return __all__ its items. It's a working solution though